# Can a woman/female lead prayer?

Tags: salat, women, imam-al-jamaah

Is it permissible for women to lead the congregational prayers?

Will the prayers of those praying under her leadership be void, if they did unknowingly or were misled?

*Background:* [Women promote mosques ‘for all’ in Britain](http://www.dawn.com/news/1035219/women-promote-mosques-for-all-in-britain)

*Answers should be backed with some source.*

Answer (score 7):

> A woman can lead the Salat only if all the followers are women;
>   however, if all of the followers are men or there is a congregation of
>   men and women, then the Imam must be a man.

In this case it is recommended that the leading woman stand at the first line and not in front of others.

**Reference:**

[The qualifications of the Imam of Salat al-Jamaat](http://www.islamic-laws.com/congregationprayer.htm)

Answer (score 4):

A women may not lead a man (whether they are old or young) in salat at all.  Though it is fine for a women to lead women in salat, and there is some differences among scholars in this.  There is a Hadith:

> لاَ تَؤُمَّنَّ امْرَأَةٌ رَجُلاً
>
> No woman should be appointed as Imam over a man

But this hadith is not authentic and is weak, but there are authentic Ahadeeth which support the meaning, the Prophet (Peace and Blessings be upon him) said:

> لَنْ يُفْلِحَ قَوْمٌ وَلَّوْا أَمْرَهُمُ امْرَأَةً
>
> Never will succeed such a nation as makes a woman their ruler

[صحيح بخاري (Bukari)](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/92/50)

Another is, The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said:

> خير صفوف النساء آخرها
>
> the best of the woman's row is the last

[صحيح مسلم (Muslim)](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/94)

Ibn Uthaymeen said:

> And this is proof that women have no place in the front, and the Imam
>   is in the front, so if the Imamat of Women is correct then the
>   position of the women would still not be flipped, so that would mean
>   that a women would have been put in front of the men and that is not
>   supported by the Shariah.

الشرح الممتع صـ312و313

Comment: I would like to add to the above answer. This is not putting the women down its more of a ....if you think about it...you will be more distracted if the women is in front of the prayer and you are behind her...

Comment: what if the woman is leading a family of male and female mahrams. What's the issue with that. I mean there wouldn't any of lust involved or anything.